# Why JQuery hide() and show() does not work?

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I have a simple DIV and can't get it to hide() and show().

I guess I am doing it right but can not find what is wrong with it.

```
<div id="thediv" >hola</div>
<input type="button" value="click to show">This is the div content</input>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#thediv").hide();
    alert($("div#thediv").hide().attr("id"));
});

$("button").click( function() {
    $("div#thediv").show();
    alert('click');
});
```

Also, I created a fiddle at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rt9Fc/)"http://jsfiddle.net/rt9Fc/".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put your click handler inside document.ready and change your selector to `$("input:button")` -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div#thediv").hide();
    alert($("div#thediv").hide().attr("id"));
    $("input:button").click(function () {
        $("div#thediv").show();
        alert('click');
    });
});
```

Demo `--->` [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rt9Fc/4/)

Answer (score 5):

There is more proper version of your code: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rt9Fc/8/)

HTML:

```
<div id="thediv">hola</div>
<input type="button" value="click to show"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var $myDiv = $("#thediv");
    $myDiv.hide();
    alert($myDiv.attr("id"));

   $("input[type=button]").on('click', function() {
      $myDiv.show();
      alert('click');
    });
});
```

Some useful notes:

- cache finding DOM elements beacuse they are expensive to find
- use on instead of click, it works faster
- `$function()` is an alias to document.ready, it's faster to write and less bytes to send over the network :)
- you don't have to use div#id selectors, #id is enough because it should be unique in your page, moreover that way after jquery will use findElementById javascript function it will not have to perform additional check for div.
- there is nice article about jQuery performance: [artzstudio](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/)
- input should not be split into open and close tag.

Probably you wanted to have this:

HTML:

```
<div id="thediv">
    hola
    <input type="button" value="click to show"/>
</div>
```

That way we can optimise JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var $myDiv = $("#thediv");
    $myDiv.hide();
    alert($myDiv.attr("id"));

   $myDiv.find("input[type=button]").on('click', function() {
      $myDiv.show();
      alert('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change button `selector`: as you were using simple `<input type='button'/>` still if you want to use `$('button')` change your markup to `<button></button>`

```
$("#thediv").hide();
alert($("div#thediv").hide().attr("id"));


$("input[type='button']").click( function() {
    $("#thediv").show();

});
```

**DEMO** `-->` [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rt9Fc/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your button  selector to `:button` or use input. `button` selector is used for `<button>Somebutton</button>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var $thediv = $('#thediv').hide(); //Cache the object here. Also you can shain it through

    $(":button").click( function() {
    $thediv.show();
    alert('click');
});
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSdpn/)**

If you have id, don't prefix it with tagname. it will make the selector slower. So just use `#thediv` instead of `div#thediv`. Also try to cache the jquery object to a variable if you are using it in multiple places, this will avoid calling the jquery object creation everythime.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to button

```
<div id="thediv">hola</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click to show"/>
```

Use this Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div#thediv").hide();
alert($("div#thediv").attr("id"));
});

$("input#btn").click( function() {
$("div#thediv").show();
alert('click');
});
```